# Django : saving form to database

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

So I have the following model :

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        ingredients = models.TextField(max_length=200,help_text="Put the ingredients required for the recepies here !")
        instructions = models.TextField(max_length=500)

        posted_on = models.DateTimeField('Posted On')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title
```

Now what I want to do is that I have a front-end in html called add.html which has a form like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<head><title>New Recipe</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Add A new Recipe Here</h1>

<form action="/recipes/add/" method="post">
{% csrf_token  %}

<label>ID<label>
<input type="number" name="id"></input><br />

<label>Title </label>
<input type ="text" name="title"><br />

<label>Ingredients</label>
<input type="text" name="ingredients" />
<br />

<label>Instructions </label>
<input type="text" name="instructions" />
...
```

Here is how I am saving the form using `ModelForm`:

```
def add(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():

                        form.save()
                        #redirect
                        return HttpResponse("Thank you")
                else:
                        return HttpResponse("Form Not Valid")
        else:
                form = RecipeForm()

                context = Context({'form':form,})
                context.update(csrf(request))
                template = loader.get_template('myApp/add.html')
                return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

When I run this I always get `"form Invalid"`
So now my problem is, Should the html form add.html have the EXACT mappings as my model  Recipe ?
If yes  ,then

1. How do I add the corresponding `types` in the html form (for `posted_on`) ?
2. How do I handle the `id` that is implicitly created by `syncdb`?
3. Is there any alternative ?

I have just started to learn Django

Answer (score 4):

1) Change `posted_on` to automatically add the date posted.

```
posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

2) Django will handle the pk id creation for you.

3) Why not use a `ModelForm` for this? [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

```
class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
```

You can either use `exclude` or `include` on `fields` to make sure your form only contains the fields from `Recipe` that you want to include in your form.

Answer (score 2):

**models.py**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.TextField(max_length=200,help_text="Put the ingredients required for the recepies here !")
    instructions = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

**page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head><title>New Recipe</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Add A new Recipe Here</h1>

<form action="/recipes/add/" method="post">
{% csrf_token  %}
     {% form.as_p %}
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:url'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Error")
    return render(request, 'myApp/add.html', {'form': RecipeForm()})
```

Comment: This is not what i want . I want the views to add the data to the db. In your `page.html` There is  way a user can input the fields . :(

Comment: yeah, that's what I did. My views can save the data into your db. I use your RecipeForm() and my page.html has a form that can input data then submit

Comment: You always get form invalid because there are no data submitted. The form you construct is another form, it's not your ModelForm. Just try and you will learn.

Comment: @Deepanker: your data is saved to the database when `form.save()` is called. Cathy is right about that.